# Flutter - No compatible iOS versions between Flutterfire and Geofire (pods)

Tags: firebase, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies, geofire

I'm trying to get all my dependencies updated for null safety and the following scenario when I run pod install:

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
cloud_functions: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 6.1.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 7.3.0)

    flutter_geofire (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
        GeoFire/Database (= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
          Firebase/Database (~> 7.8.0)
```

Checking the native ios geofire and flutterfire library, I realize that the current version from geofire for iOS aims firebase database ~> 7.8 and the previously one database ~> 6.x.x.
Flutterfire null safety aims firebase 7.3.

Turning actually impossible to find a version with null-safety compatible between flutterfire and geofire.

I have tried before completely remove my pods with the commands without success:

```
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
pod cache clean --all
pod deintegrate
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod repo update
pod install
```

Any suggestions? thank you!

Comment: I was able to finally resolve this sort of infinite loop of cocoapods incompatible errors with Geofire. These are the steps I followed: 

1) Ran `flutter clean` from the mac terminal (not the Android Studio terminal)
2) Updated the **pubspec.yaml** file with latest resolvable versions of your packages 
3) Ran `flutter pub get`
4) Edited file: ...ios/.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios/flutter_geofire.podspec - updated this field: **ios.deployment_target = '11.0'** (was 12.0)
updated this field: **s.ios.dependency 'GeoFire', '~> 4.3.0'** (was 4.3)
5) Ran `pod install --repo-update`